# Microsoft emotions API: Recognize Emotions in Video using Swift and XCode

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

So basically the app I'm trying to built will have the real time video emotion API. So while the user takes a video of him/her self it will send realtime emotion based on facial expression (in JSON format ofc). Looks very possible using C#. I just dont know how I should go about it using Swift and XCode. Should I invoke Alamofire? But then how would I pass in the frames? I looked in Core Video Kit but there's absolutely nothing out there regarding that. Could someone help? If its possible using Objective C then let me know as well.
Thanks in advance :)